# Is there a way to change the flag associated with a language?

Tags: manjaro, language, i18n

I am using Manjaro Linux with everything up to date.

In my taskbar, I have the following:

[image]

Is there a way I can change the flag associated with a language selection? I want to keep the language but only change the flag.

I'm not sure if this is doable, but I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1):

Your need to change sy.svg in `/usr/share/xfce4/xkb/flags/` to what ever you want (make sure your new file is also named sy and is a svg(Scalable Vector Graphics), but you need to do it as sudo or root. The easiest way to to that is open Thunar file manger and click File then Thunar Root. Next delete sy.svg in `/usr/share/xfce4/xkb/flags/`. Then copy your new file (make sure it it also named sy.svg) and paste it in `/usr/share/xfce4/xkb/flags/`.

Edit: If you want to find a new file on the internet just search: `(What ever country your want) flag svg`. Yet again make sure it is a .svg.

Edit 2:You can also use one of the flags already in in `/usr/share/xfce4/xkb/flags/`.